# Get files from a given URL on the basis of pattern passed using Perl on Unix

Tags: perl

I have been told that a given URL contains several xml and text files and I need to download all the xml files starting with AAA(that is AAA*.xml) inside a given directory.

Credentials to access that URL are provided to me.

Please not that size of xml files could be in GBs.

I have used below code to achieve the same-

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP;
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $username ='scott';
my $password='tiger';

 # Create HTTP request object
  my $req =  HTTP::Request->new( GET => "https://url.com/");
 # Authenticate the user
  $req->authorization_basic( $username , $password);
  my   $res = $browser->request( $req , ':content_file' => '/fold/AAA1.xml');

  print $res->status_line, "\n";
```

It prints 200 OK status but I am not able to get the file. Any suggestions?

Man

Answer (score 3):

If the server doesn't allow you to receive a folder list (i.e. Apache without "Options +Indexes"), you will not GET the collection of files.
But, having the list, you can filter it with a regexpr like /AAA.*/, and with [LWP::Simple module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aSimple), it's easy to get it

Comment: Its a secured URL and authentication is getting failed while it works when I am providing the same manually on web browser.

Comment: So, probably you need to mechanize with WWW::Mechanize module